# How to regex string in php

Tags: php, regex

I have the string that is the html code and i want to get some tag from this html. Tag like below:

```
    <td width="33%" align="left" class="MID">
    <a href="ShowDOTCoByState.cfm?STATE=US&PHY_ST=IA">IOWA</a>
    </td>
```

How can i get tags using regex?

Comment: Nobody can understand.

Comment: @vks Can you add class="MID" to your regex,please

Comment: did you wantb to match the whole tag?

Comment: Is your objective to collect <td> tags or the <a> tag? or just URLs associated with the state name?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

better use this :

```
<?php
$html='<td width="33%" align="left" class="MID"><a href="ShowDOTCoByState.cfm?STATE=US&amp;PHY_ST=IA">IOWA</a></td>" id="blabah" >help</a>';
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);
echo $dom->getElementsByTagName('a')->item(0)->nodeValue;
```

this will get the value of the text written for link.

demo here : https://eval.in/202356

or if you are so fond on using regex :

```
<td.*?class="MID"[^>]*[\s\S]*?<\/td>
```

demo here : http://regex101.com/r/aS9pV1/1

Comment: thank, it worked. I will confirm it

Comment: Can you tell me where to learn regex ? Thank you very much.

Comment: @vmduan sure sir, you can start from http://regexone.com/ I started from there

Answer (score 0):

```
(<td(?=.*?class="MID")[^>]*>(?:(?!<\/td>).)*<\/td>)
```

Try this.Add flags `g` and `s`.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/mM8xF8/2

Comment: Can you add class="MID" to your regex,please

Comment: yes i only want class="MID"